# How Dithereum System Contracts actually work?

Tags: private-blockchain, dithereum

As I know the transaction fee distributions, system rewards distributions and all are happening in the Dithereum System Contracts.  So, Is there any documentation or resources where I can learn more about them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dithereum System Contracts** are the smart contracts working at blockchain system level.

As mentioned in the **Dithereum** official documentation:

https://docs.dithereum.org/#/consensus?id=system-contracts

> The management of the current validators are all done by the system
> contracts.
>
> - Proposal Responsible for managing access to validators and managing    validator proposals and votes.  Validators Responsible for ranking
> - Management of validators, staking and unstaking operations,    distribution of block rewards, etc..
> - Punish Responsible for    punishing operations against active validators who are not working    properly.

These smart contracts are created at the time of genesis deployment of the **Dithereum** platform.

The source codes can be found in the **Dithereum** github repository.

https://github.com/Dithereum/System-Contracts/tree/master/smart%20contracts

Comment: Thanks for describing and explaining easy words for the Dithereum System Contract. @Yogesh